# multiprocessing - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: multiprocessing, python-3.8, rasa-x

I want to run a Rasa-Project whicgh was coded from another group. Rasa installation works fine (also rasa shell command). Now i want to use the Rasa UI by installing rasa-x. Following Errors appears in the Terminal:

[Terminal Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VmGr.png)

I looked into the Folder .../multiprocessing/... and the spawn.py and synchronize.py folders are there. Anyone a idea ? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pip uninstall uvloop fixed my Problem.